# "worthy of mention(ing)" or "worthy of a mention(ing)"?

Tags: indefinite-article, phrase-choice, register

> That kind of happening would have definitely been **worthy of mention**.

or

> That kind of happening would have definitely been **worthy of a mention**.

or

> That kind of happening would have definitely been **worthy of mentioning**.

or

> That kind of happening would have definitely been **worthy of a mentioning**.

?

Comment: All wrong, "mentionworthy". :)

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion:

> ... would be definitely **worth mentioning**.

Comment: +1 for the conversational neutral-register option.

Comment: I feel like "worth mentioning" and "worthy of mention" have rather distinct and different connotations. "Worth mentioning" has a connotation of something you you should mention to whom its relevant as a courtesy. Whereas "worthy of mention" has an air of something that is somehow impressive or a great accomplishment. I guess the main distinction as I see it is that something is "worth mentioning" because the listener deserves to hear about it, whereas something is "worthy of mention" because the thing itself deserves to be known.

Comment: As such, I don't think the two can be used interchangeably unless the thing being mentioned is something that fits both categories of something the listener deserves to hear and something that deserves to be heard.

Answer (score 3):

**worth mentioning** as Alex_ander offers is in neutral conversational register.

**worthy of mention**  is in a slightly elevated register.

Forget the other two options, as they're not idiomatic.

**worth a mention** is in a more casual register.

Comment: worth mentioning & worth a mention are both common (UK).  Don't think I've heard "worthy of mention" - it doesn't sound 'wrong', but maybe a little pompous in comparison.

Comment: I've heard "worthy of mention" used in meetings, though almost entirely in the negative, eg. "I didn't consider it worthy of mention". I've also heard it used to refer to people in this way.

Comment: @JTPenguin: It needn't be negative. Something can be *certainly worthy of mention*. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=certainly+worthy+of+mention&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccertainly%20worthy%20of%20mention%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Algy Taylor: As I wrote, "a slightly elevated register", though I wouldn't go as far as to call it "pompous" by any means. But such judgments are subjective, I will admit.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I've just spent 20 minutes having fun playing with this, I can't believe I didn't know about this before!

Answer (score 2):

According the the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mention), **mention** can be a mass noun, which does not require an **a**, or a countable noun which does require an **a**. The Oxford Dictionary states that the countable form is British only, but the American dictionary [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mention) also describes a countable form.

**mentioning** could be an active participle or a gerund derived from the verb **mention**: in this context, it is an active participle, which must not be used with an **a**.

The first three of your examples are therefore correct: the fourth is not correct because an active participle does not take an **a**.

---

Note that **definitely** is a mid-position adverb, and mid-position adverbs go after the first auxiliary verb- in this case, after **would**.

**[happening](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/happening)** can in principle be used as a singular noun, but it has a 1960's hippie feel. **[Event](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/event)** would probably be more appropriate, unless you are talking about an event where people smoked lots of hash. 
If you apply those two corrections, you get:

> That kind of event would definitely have been worthy of mention.